# Emacs terminal column width (julia / python shell)

Tags: python, shell, emacs, julia

I am trying to use Emacs as an Integrated Computing Environment for Julia & Python. `ESS` (Emacs Speaks Statistics) is the plugin that I use to interactively send selected code for REPL evaluation.

`C-c C-c` selects the code and starts `Julia` interpreter the first time the combination is used, in subsequent executions it uses the existing `Julia` session.

The challenge I am facing is that the terminal window for `Julia` (this is the case even with `Python`) for some reason only uses `80 columns` for the output.

For example the following code if executed inside `Julia` session would print the DataFrame `df` in three groups which are wrapped at 80 columns. Even though my window size can easily handle over 200 characters.

```
 using DataFrames
 df=readtable("../../data/titanic/data/train.csv")


 julia> df[1:2, :]
 2x12 DataFrame
 | Row | PassengerId | Survived | Pclass |
 |-----|-------------|----------|--------|
 | 1   | 1           | 0        | 3      |
 | 2   | 2           | 1        | 1      |

 | Row | Name                                                  | Sex      |
 |-----|-------------------------------------------------------|----------|
 | 1   | "Braund, Mr. Owen Harris"                             | "male"   |
 | 2   | "Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)" | "female" |

 | Row | Age  | SibSp | Parch | Ticket      | Fare    | Cabin | Embarked |
 |-----|------|-------|-------|-------------|---------|-------|----------|
 | 1   | 22.0 | 1     | 0     | "A/5 21171" | 7.25    | NA    | "S"      |
 | 2   | 38.0 | 1     | 0     | "PC 17599"  | 71.2833 | "C85" | "C"      |
```

I have even tried manually firing up a `Julia` session inside Emacs shell `M-x shell` and even that would result in 80 column wrapping.

But the same code if I execute in a `Julia` session running inside a regular `Mac OSX Terminal` would correctly use the entire width of the terminal.

**Workaround / Potential Culprit**

If i execute `stty size` on my `OS X Terminal` I get proper output which represent the actual size of my terminal for example `24 157`.

But if I execute `stty size` inside Emacs shell `M-x shell` I get `0 0`. No matter what the size of the Emacs window is the result of `stty` inside emacs is always `0 0`.

When I manually change the `stty` settings, let's say `stty rows 24 cols 160` and then execute `julia` I am able to get my outputs from julia to consume all 160 columns.

**Question**

1. How can I make Emacs dynamically adjust stty (settings) or whatever facility that would give the intended result.
2. If #1 is not possible and this is a compromise I have to deal with is it possible to set a static stty settings in .emacs file which would be used by default.

I have tried this even on a Linux machine (CentOS) and I have the same issue there.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In the emacs M-x shell I'm looking at, there's an envvar of EMACS=t that you could use to do stty settings from inside of a .bashrc or equivalent.

However, if you use "M-x ansi-term", terminal sizing is fully supported, including dynamic resize, serious terminal emulation, etc.  More info: https://masteringemacs.org/article/running-shells-in-emacs-overview - I'd strongly recommend this path if it's possible for you (assuming noone knows an even better one).

Hopefully you'll be able to use the ansi-term, but if the M-x shell is required, than a .profile or .bashrc line like this might work.  The downside is that it would per-user, and users do wildly different things in those scripts.

```
[ _"$EMACS" = _t ] && stty cols 160
```